# How do I send keyboard keys combination in selenium webdriver (java)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to send 1999 to a text box in Selenium  WebDriver (java). The following code is not working when I try to combine the key strokes into a string before sendkeys:

```
String allKeys = Keys.NUMPAD1 + Keys.NUMPAD9 + Keys.NUMPAD9 + Keys.NUMPAD9;
```

Am getting this error:

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s)
>   org.openqa.selenium.Keys, org.openqa.selenium.Keys

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using:

```
String allKeys = Keys.NUMPAD1 + Keys.NUMPAD9 + Keys.NUMPAD9 + Keys.NUMPAD9;
```

You should use:

```
driver.findelement(by.xpath(xpathExpr)).sendkeys(Keys.NUMPAD1, Keys.NUMPAD9, Keys.NUMPAD9, Keys.NUMPAD9);
```

Or use:

```
String allKeys = "1999";
driver.findelement(by.xpath(xpathExpr)).sendkeys(allKeys);
```

Answer (score 2):

why not use send keys.

```
driver.findelement(by.xpath(xpathExpr)).sendkeys("1999");
```

Comment: thanks for all the help. I was actually learning to use the Keys class. yes I could have sent "1999". But I wanted to do it using the "Keys"

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It works for me!

```
driver.findelement(by.xpath(xpathExpr)).SendKeys(keys.NumberPad1+keys.NumberPad9+keys.NumberPad9+keys.NumberPad9);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question** : How do I send keyboard keys combination in selenium webdriver (java)?

**Answer** : You can send keyboard keys using below method

**Method 1 :**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Year")).sendKeys(Keys.NUMPAD9);
```

**Method 2 :**

```
String allKeys = "1999";

driver.findElement(By.id("Year")).sendKeys(allKeys);
```

**Method 3 :**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Year")).sendKeys("1999");
```

[image]